# Как изменить расстояние между картинками в Slick slider

Tags: html, css, slick.js

Как увеличить (либо уменьшить) расстояние между картинками в слайдере. Уже пробовала *margin* и *padding*, но ничего не помогает.

Двигается не отдельная картинка, а полностью блок. Нужно чтобы их было три в строке.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sliderTeam').slick({
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1, 
    });
});
```

```css
#container {
    max-width: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}
.sliderTeam {
    max-width: 510px;
    margin: 55px 0px 0px 0px;
    height: 300px;     
}
.team__foto img {
    width: 100px;
    position: relative;
    top: -20px;     
}
.team__foto {
    border: 4px solid #1489d9;
    width: 90px;
    height: 77px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 12px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <div class="sliderTeam">
        <div class="team">
            <div class="team__foto">
                <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/1600/worker-female.png">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="team">
            <div class="team__foto team__foto-move">
                <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/1600/worker-female.png">
            </div>            
        </div>
        <div class="team">
            <div class="team__foto">
                <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/1600/worker-female.png">
            </div>            
        </div>
        <div class="team">
            <div class="team__foto">
                <img src="https://png.icons8.com/color/1600/worker-female.png">
            </div>
        </div>       
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Чтобы установить собственную ширину добавите в инициализацию слайдера параметр `variableWidth: true`.

Затем в css можно указать свою ширину: `.slick-slide { width: 120px; }`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.sliderTeam').slick({
        slidesToScroll: 1, 
        variableWidth: true
    });
});
```

```css
#container {
    max-width: 950px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    max-height: 100%;
}
.sliderTeam {
    max-width: 360px;
}
.team__foto img {
    width: 100px;  
}
.team__foto {
    border: 4px solid #1489d9;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
.slick-slide {
    width: 120px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
    <div class="sliderTeam">
        <div class="team">
            <div class="team__foto">
                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-drX8I-WkQHA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAX8/6NuG1L4_j-c/photo.jpg?sz=128">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="team">
            <div class="team__foto team__foto-move">
                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-drX8I-WkQHA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAX8/6NuG1L4_j-c/photo.jpg?sz=128">
            </div>            
        </div>
        <div class="team">
            <div class="team__foto">
                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-drX8I-WkQHA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAX8/6NuG1L4_j-c/photo.jpg?sz=128">
            </div>            
        </div>
        <div class="team">
            <div class="team__foto">
                <img src="https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-drX8I-WkQHA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAX8/6NuG1L4_j-c/photo.jpg?sz=128">
            </div>
        </div>       
    </div>
</div>
```